# Angular does not run on an IIS server after removing the # symbol from the URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, iis

I am developing a web platform using **Angular** JS as a client side framework and **.Net** as a Server side framework for creating **Rest** webservices.
Now, my goal is to remove the **#** symbol. I have followed these steps:

1. Configure `$locationProvider` and set `html5Mode` to `true`.
2. Add the `base` tag to `index.html` file  (`<base href="/">`).
3. Configure the **iis** server for rewrite mode.

After successfully completing these steps, the **#** is removed from the url and I am able to navigate between routes but **Angular** does not run correctly (for example: `ng-show` and `ng-disabled` directives and my app's controllers are not working).

I have tried to add `angular-csp.css` to my `index.html` file and add a `ng-csp` directive to its `body` tag but the problem persists.

Is this problem related to a client side configuration (some **Angular** configs) or a Server side configuration (**iis** server configs) and how to solve it?

**EDIT**

The project runs correctly on my local **node http server**. I have tested all functionalities locally and no errors in the browser's console.

Comment: Have you looked at the client side to see if there's any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I am running the Angular project successfully on a node http server to test it locally. But when things get online, there begins the journey of errors :/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes, no errors in the browser's console and all functionalities are working perfectly.

Comment: Then you should start making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest make a very basic site and add features on until you're able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SO WEIRD!** I solved the problem and I don't know how and why. I have tried to place all **javascript** files in different folders and I ended up with a working app once I placed them in the **js** folder. Locally, the app works whether all **javascript** files are located in the **js** folder or not. But when things get on the **iis** server,  I found that it only works when **javascript** files are located in the **js** folder. I have searched a lot for a reason but nothing found.

**EDIT:**

Finally, I have found the reason why my app works well when I placed **Javascript** files in the **js** folder. Actually, it is not about **js** folder naming specifically, but it is related to a config for accepting only specific folders naming and here is my **web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular">
                    <match url=".*\.html|css/|img/|fonts/|js/|data/|lib/|templates/|favicon.ico" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So if I want answer myself: it is an iis server side configuration (**web.config**). At first I putted my javascript files in a folder called "**components**" which is not listed between the accepted url naming in web.config. As a result, the server wouldn't allow the access to **BASE_URL/components** and all javascript files in components folder won't be loaded in the browser.